# Dart type that is implemented by everything

Tags: dart

I'm not quite sure how to phrase this but I basically want to write a function like this:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

int countBroadcastStreams(List<Stream<Object>> streams) {
  return streams.where((s) => s.isBroadcast).length;
}

void main() {
  final a = StreamController<int>.broadcast();
  final b = StreamController<String>.broadcast();
  countBroadcastStreams([
    a.stream,
    b.stream,
  ]);
}
```

This works, however if I change one of the `StreamController`s to `StreamController<Null>` then it doesn't because `Null` is the only type that doesn't inherit `Object`.

So my question is: which type should I use instead of `Object` so it works with `Null` too? `dynamic` seems to work, but is that the best option? Does it introduce additional runtime cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the problem comes from the `Object` type. Try to explicitly specify that the Stream objects can be null:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

int countBroadcastStreams(List<Stream<Object?>> streams) {
  return streams.where((s) => s != null && s.isBroadcast).length;
}

void main() {
  final a = StreamController<int>.broadcast();
  final b = StreamController<Null>.broadcast();
  print(countBroadcastStreams([
    a.stream,
    b.stream,
  ]));
}

// console log: 2
```

Specify the nullable type for the stream objects: `List<Stream<Object**?**>> streams`.

Comment: Great! I updated the answer for future references. If it's correct, we can just delete these comments.